# How to dynamically bind a run's background brush to a resource?

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, flowdocument, dynamic-binding

In my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colorBrush1" Color="Orange" Opacity="1"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colorBrush2" Color="Green" Opacity="1"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In my code-behind:

```
Run run = new Run("My name is Bob!");
run.SetResourceReference(ForegroundProperty, "colorBrush1");
run.SetResourceReference(BackgroundProperty, "colorBrush2");

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);

this.flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

*Expected Result:* Run appears with foreground color and background color as defined in app.xaml above.

*Actual Result:* Foreground color works (appears orange), but **background remains transparent.**

**Why doesn't binding the run's background to a resource work, like it does with foreground???**  I tried adding the run and paragraph to the FlowDocument first and then binding, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that BackgroundProperty needs to be clarified.  This is what you want:

```
        Run run = new Run("My name is Bob!");
        run.SetResourceReference(Run.ForegroundProperty, "colorBrush1");
        run.SetResourceReference(Run.BackgroundProperty, "colorBrush2");
```

A real mystery is why just writing "ForegroundProperty" works.

Comment: `ForegroundProperty` is inherited from quite a basic class so you can just reference the property of the control your code is located in as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear, concise answer!  The silent failure had me stumped.  :)